# How can I replicate magic_quotes functionality in a XAMPP PHP7.4 server?

Tags: php, xampp, magic-quotes

First of all, I understand that magic_quotes causes all kinds of problems and has no place in modern PHP. I'm in a very specific situation where I've upgraded XAMPP from PHP 5 to PHP 7.4 for an intranet site comprised of more than 5000 files. Suddenly, all kinds of SQL INSERT queries are breaking when the user-generated string has single or double quotes in it. It's in no way feasible for me to go through and wrap every variable across these 5000 files with the add_slashes function, so I need to come up with some way to globally apply the same logic that magic_quotes did. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use PDO or `escape_string` function at least.

Comment: Neither magic_quotes nor addslashes fixes SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: @AlexHowansky is there any way to apply this globally, not line-by-line?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code, but probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to update this application [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).  However, I am pretty sure that's not going to happen.  So, in a header file or one that is included before any database operation ([auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) maybe), just map the superglobals to `addslashes`.  You can add `$_COOKIE` if needed:

```
$_POST = array_map('addslashes', $_POST);
$_GET  = array_map('addslashes', $_GET);
```

Obviously this won't handle multidimensional arrays so you'll have to use a recursive function:

```
function addslashes_recursive($v) {
    $v = is_array($v) ? array_map('addslashes_recursive', $v) : addslashes($v);    
    return $v;
}

$_POST = addslashes_recursive($_POST);
$_GET  = addslashes_recursive($_GET);
```

Comment: This works, thank you. This is definitely a stop gap, we're rebuilding the whole thing in Laravel within the next year. This is also completely internal to their company, so I'm not worried about malicious SQL injection.